# È corretto dire 'stiamo declinando'?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, word-meaning

In una conversazione avrei voluto dire:

> Eppure c'è gente che crede a simili fandonie, che, peraltro, è la ragione per cui stiamo inesorabilmente **declinando**.

Però, poco prima di pronunciare la frase testé riportata, ho pensato che 'stiamo inesorabilmente declinando' — col senso 'siamo inesorabilmente in declino' — poteva non essere una forma corretta dell'uso del verbo 'declinare'.

Allora ho detto:

> Eppure c'è gente che crede a simili fandonie, che, peraltro, è la ragione per cui stiamo inesorabilmente **collassando**.

C'è qualcuno che conferma se 'stiamo declinando', nel senso di 'siamo in declino', è corretto?

Il fatto è che a me suona male, ma non sono riuscito a capire perché.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

E' perfettamente corretto usare "stiamo declinando"; "declinare" ha un'accezione figurata che giudicando dal contesto potrebbe corrispondere perfettamente a quello che volevi dire; citando [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/declinare/):

> [...]
>   1. intr. (aus. avere)
>   [...]
>   b. fig. Volgere verso il termine: il giorno ormai declinava; anche sostantivato: il declinare della vita; sul d. del secolo. Diminuire, dileguarsi: la potenza, la gloria, la fama declinano; la sua salute declina a poco a poco; abbassarsi: la febbre sta declinando.
>   [...]

"collassare" ha allo stesso modo un'accezione figurata che, sempre giudicando dal contesto, potrebbe corrispondere anch'essa perfettamente a quello che volevi dire; citando [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/collassare/):

> [...]
>   3. v. intr.
>   [...]
>   c. fig. Essere nell’impossibilità di funzionare: il sistema dei semafori ha collassato.
>   [...]

Quindi come vedi tecnicamente andrebbero bene tutte e due, ma il loro significato è in effetti differente; dipende da cosa vuoi dire esattamente.

"collassare" è una parola più forte di "declinare", perché nelle sue accezioni più comuni è usata per descrivere situazioni di grave compromissione, come quella di un'organo / di un'organismo in campo medico (e ovviamente anche di contesti molto più generali), dove la situazione non è più recuperabile;

"declinare" invece è una parola meno forte di "collassare", perché nelle sue accezioni più comuni è usata per descrivere situazioni non ancora gravemente compromesse, anche se in fase di peggioramento e volte alla compromissione totale (eventualmente) in un termine più o meno lungo;

In definitiva, se la situazione fosse ancora recuperabile userei "declinare"; se la situazione non fosse più recuperabile userei invece "collassare".